# Why does JavaScript function not show in Visual Studio 2022 navigation bar's class/type drop down, unless it contains a var declaration?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2022

In the following code, only fnB() appears in VS22's navigation bar's class/type (middle) drop-down.

```js
var someModule = {
  fnA: function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  },

  fnB: function (a, b) {
    var c;

    return a + b;
  },
};
```

[image: Screen grab of class/type navigation drop-down]

fnA() appears in the drop-down, only when I add a 'var x;' or similar declaration, which seems odd. It's like the compiler is already in-lining the function. How do I fix this to ensure ALL functions show in the navigation bar?

Comment: If you feel the Visual Studio's behaviour is incorrect, you should raise a bug ~ https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, does it still happen if you use [method definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)? For example, `var someModule = { faA() {...}, fnB() {...} };`

Comment: Phil, thanks for your comment. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious before raising it as a bug but will do so if no one can explain it away.

Comment: Boaz, I wasn't aware of method definition shorthand, so thanks for that. Nevertheless, having tested it behavior is same with either syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Having reported this 'bug' I got a delightful 'answer' from Maria Solano in Microsoft. Apparently the 'reason' for this behavior is that "The UI is confusing" and does not do what one expects.

Also, "Because a and b are just parameters in fnA then they’re not included in the second dropdown, which means that fnA will never be selected in the first dropdown and hence it’s not listed when expanded". The first assertion makes sense, but I'm still seeking an explanation of how the second assertion follows from that.

Upshot is - it's not a bug, it's a massive design flaw :-)